# want to Upload Image in the background of Ellipse through C#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

my XAML Code looks like this

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Ellipse x:Name="dp" Height="250" Width="250" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/img.jpg"/>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
            <Button Content="Upload Image" Margin="236,0,0,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

& want to change Background image by Clicking the button("Upload Image")
& this is my Backend Coding in C#

```
FileOpenPicker fop = new FileOpenPicker();
        fop.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        StorageFile file = await fop.PickSingleFileAsync();
        IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        if (file!=null)
        {
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(stream.));
            ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
            brush.ImageSource = bmp;
        }
```

I am Begineer in Window Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Di you try doing setting the fill of the elipse, if the code that gets the file is working ok then you should be able to do this

```
 dp.Fill = brush;
```

also you have a typo

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(stream.)); extra . after stream
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(stream));
```

Comment: yes, it works I have to just add "bmp.SetSource(stream);" this line in above condition... Thank You So much